# Why does this code act differently in Chrome and Firefox / How do I fix it?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

In Chrome, if I view this code at above 1090px wide, then reduce the width to below 1090px, then bring it back to above 1090px, the right column shows below the left column. The way it looks/acts in firefox is more like I'm trying to accomplish.

My current version of Chrome is: Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I found I had to use the "expand snippet" option to see the behavior here.

```css
.fourSquareImages img{
    max-width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
#leftImages {
    width: 65%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
}

#rightImages {
    width: 35%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1090px){
  #leftImages {
      width: 48%;
      display: inline-block;
  }
  
  #rightImages {
      width: 48%;
      display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fourSquareImages">
    <div id="leftImages">
      <img border="0" src="http://www.davidreynoldsjewelryandcoin.com/images/estate/deco_bracelet.jpg" width="243" height="186" alt="Art Deco Bracelets"><br>
      <span class="caption">Art Deco Bracelets</span><br>

      <img border="0" src="http://www.davidreynoldsjewelryandcoin.com/images/estate/pansy.jpg" width="243" height="186" alt="Diamond Broaches"><br>
      <span class="caption">Diamond Broaches</span><br>
    </div>
    <div id="rightImages">
      <img border="0" src="http://www.davidreynoldsjewelryandcoin.com/images/estate/rolex_yacht_master.jpg" width="243" height="186" alt="Rolex Watches."><br>
      <span class="caption">Rolex Watches</span><br>

      <img border="0" src="http://www.davidreynoldsjewelryandcoin.com/images/estate/opal_ring.jpg" width="243" height="186" alt="Opals"><br>
      <span class="caption">Opals</span><br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Same code: https://jsfiddle.net/1gjn8xz7/

Comment: If you remove the display:inline-block from the media query, they behave the same on both browsers.

Comment: I've moved on to use a different approach in this instance, but I think the question still needs an answer. The fact that Chrome displays it correctly, reacts correctly sizing down, then incorrectly when sizing back up needs an explanation.

Comment: its called the chrome display inline block bug. https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+display+inline+block+bug&oq=chrome+displays+inlin&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.5168j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @rx2347 Thanks. I followed that link and then this [Bug Report](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/14179981?hl=en) with no reply after several months.

Comment: just saying its all known and out there. the best solution for this is [css-grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The media query max-width is 1090px. This means that the media query will only be applied if the maximum size is at 1090px wide. Otherwise, the web browser will ignore the media query. One way to solve this problem is to create several media queries for different sizes. The other way would be to delete the media query. Deleting the media query would make it so that all the style rules will apply no matter the screen width and height.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked by the OP. (me)